# Lilypond: paper spacing variables not being respected for a score inside markup

Tags: lilypond

I'm doing some chords+lyrics song sheets, and trying to achieve a two column layout. From what I've read, the way to accomplish this is by putting scores within a markup block.

This works to get the two columns, but as soon as I do it, the \paper variables that are controlling the vertical spacing seem to be ignored. How can I get two columns and proper spacing at the same time?

Here's a simple example:
[image: Lilypond markup spacing issue]

Here's the code:

```
\version "2.18.2"

chordNames = \chordmode {
  c1 f g a:m \break
  c f g:7 c \break
}
words = \lyricmode {
  Here_are some random lyrics
  These are more lyrics
}

\paper {
  indent = #0
  ragged-right = ##t

  % padding here controls space between lyrics and next line
  system-system-spacing = #'((basic-distance . 0)
                             (minimum-distance . 0)
                             (padding . 1)
                             (stretchability . 0))
}

% Single column outside of markup is spaced according to \paper variables
\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames \chordNames
    \new Lyrics \words
  >>
  \layout { \context { \ChordNames } }
}

% Two columns inside markup do not respect \paper spacing variables
\markup {
  \vspace #3
  \score {
    <<
      \new ChordNames \chordNames
      \new Lyrics \words
    >>
    \layout { \context { \ChordNames } }
  }
  \hspace #8
  \score {
    <<
      \new ChordNames \chordNames
      \new Lyrics \words
    >>
    \layout { \context { \ChordNames } }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me.  If you'd like, I can run it past the guys on the LilyPond mail list -- or you can too.

- User list: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lilypond-user
- Bug List: http://lilypond.org/bug-reports.html

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might be a bug, but I've also found many instances where I just couldn't figure out the magic variable to set to do what I want. If you have access to submit a bug report, that would be great.